# Задать высоту элемента относительно своего пра-пра-дедушки

Tags: html, css

Есть кнопка меню, по нажатию на которую выпадает меню. Список динамический и может быть очень длинным. Нужно сделать так, чтобы высота списка никогда не была больше высоты главного контейнера и пункты списка распологались в несколько колонок (при необходимости).

Проблема в том, что список является дочерним относительно кнопки, месторасположение списка должно позиционироваться относительно этой кнопки + вклиниться в структуру html особо возможности нет (используется сторонняя библиотека компонентов Vue).
Разметку "накидал" схематическую. Мне бы сам принцип понять)

```css
.wrap{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.header{
  height: 30%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrap">
 <header class="header">
  <div class="btn">
   <ul class="menu">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </header>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: попробовать `flex-flow: column wrap;` + обертке меню `max-height: XXXpx; `

Comment: @HamSter, `flex-wrap` поможет, если у списка будет какая-нибудь высота. А вот  ее, как раз, задать и не получается, т.к. обертка списка, это маленькая кнопочка с фиксированными размерами. Я, конечно, могу ошибаться и что-то делаю не так, но уже много всяких вариантов перепробовал)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/luczg7 так имею ввиду, возможно оибаюсь

Comment: @HamSter, ну да, все правильно. Но мне высоту хотелось бы относительно основного контейнера установить). Ну, всмысле, не точные пиксели, а относительные размеры

Comment: Высота главного контейнер .wrap ? у вас задана 200px фикс. 
Так задавать ее можно и списку. А если нет такой возможности, то можно js вычислить для главного контейнера и задавать ее списку, пару строчек кода.

Comment: и такая, наверное мелочь, но если пунктов будет много, а главный контейнер по высоте не позволит всем пунктам меню удобно расположиться)) , то вот они будут вылазить за пределы страницы http://prntscr.com/ludchg , может быть стоит тогда делать по принципу мегаменю, позиционировать не относительно кнопки, а относительно шапки или главного контейнера.

Comment: @HamSter, да, много вопросов возникает). Наверное, сюда действительно надо js подключать

Comment: Хороший вопрос)) у меня часто подобные задачи возникают по подобным меню (у меня по крайней мере меню) и всегда по разному решаю и всегда с костылями))))